# How to print randomly words from list without brackets, quotes and commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
mylist = ['dog','cat','bird','lion','dragon']
```

1. I need to randomly choose 2 words from the list and each word can be printed maximally once
2. I also need it to be printed without brackets, quotes and commas, like this

```
dog cat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try sample code:

```
from random import shuffle
mylist = ['dog','cat','bird','lion','dragon']
shuffle(mylist)
print(*mylist[:2])
```

Comment: I think its inefficient for larger lists, plus the asker asked to pick 2 elements randomly not shuffle the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

You could pick two unique words from the `list` by using the `random.sample()` function:

```
import random
mylist = ['dog','cat','bird','lion','dragon']
print(*random.sample(set(mylist), 2))
```

Output (Randomized):

```
dog cat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'lion', 'dragon']
for i in range(2):
    print(mylist.pop(random.randrange(len(mylist))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import random

 random.sample(mylist([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I like the answer of @AWhiteFox as it shuffles the list and gets the first two element, that's pretty good actually but it does not apply directly to your statement here **"I need to randomly choose 2 words from the list"** but still the choice is yours. I'll also like to post my answer of mine.

```
import random

mylist = ['dog','cat','bird','lion','dragon']
print(mylist[random.randint(0,len(mylist)-1)],mylist[random.randint(0,len(mylist)-1)])
```

**Output:**

```
cat lion
```

Base on your statement here **I need to randomly choose 2 words from the list** Now what this does is just generates random numbers in the range of the size of your `list` so it literally just chooses 2 words from the list randomly by the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external file, such as a .txt or.csv file. This will allow you to have a potentially larger database of words.When making the .txt or .csv file all of the words that you would like to use have to be on word on a separate line with no spaces.You can use the line:

```
    print(choice(list(open("THEfile.txt"))),end="",sep="")
```

Before this at the start of the whole program you will have to import the random and choice libraries. This can be done like this:

```
import random
from random import choice
```

To repeat more than one word you will have to simply repeat the line,such as:

```
print(choice(list(open("THEfile.txt"))),end="",sep="")
print(choice(list(open("THEfile.txt"))),end="",sep="")
```